# Proving statement about multivariable limit.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification

Let $f:C \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ for an open set $C \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and suppose $|f(\textbf{x})-L|\leq h(||\textbf{x}||)$ for some function $h:[0,\infty) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Prove that $\lim_{k \to 0} h(k)=0 \implies \lim_{\textbf{x} \to 0}f(\textbf{x})=L.$

Attempt:Since $|f(\textbf{x})-L|$ is bounded, there is an $M>0$ with $|f(\textbf{x})-L|\leq h(||\textbf{x}||) \leq M$ for all$||\textbf{x}||$.
For $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|k|<\delta \implies |h(k)|<\frac{\epsilon}{M}.$ Then for $\delta=k$, $0<||x||<\delta \implies |f(\textbf{x})-L|\leq h(||x||) < M\frac{\epsilon}{M}=\epsilon$

Comment I am a little confused if this proof is correct, because does the inequality,$|f(\textbf{x})-L|\leq h(||x||)$ hold for all $||\textbf{x}||$?

Comment: now I realize this is off because $||x||$ is not fixed, is there a way to remediate this issue?

Edit: So now I figure that this is the correct approach here,the upper bound for $h(||x||)$ comes from the limit of $h(k)$,

For $\epsilon>0$ there is a $\delta>0$ such that $0<|k|<\delta \implies |h(k)|<\epsilon.$ Then for this $\delta$, $0<||x||<\delta \implies |f(\textbf{x})-L|\leq h(||x||) < \epsilon$

Comment: your prove is not fully correct to fix issues of $|| x||$ you can choose a ball around 0 such that $|h(x)| < \varepsilon$ and then you are done

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi do you mean $h(||x||)$?

Comment: yes,my bad @Daniel

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi is the last approach correct now?

Comment: Yes it is correct